# Global list vs global variable assignment

Tags: python, list, variables, global-variables, global

I have the following test code:

```
def test():
    m = 1
    l[1] = 1

def main():
    global l
    global m
    m = 0
    l = [0]*3
    test()
    print m
    print l

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this case, the value for the list 'l' gets updated while the value for the global variable 'm' remains unchanged. If I declare the variable 'm' as global in test(), the value gets updated. Why does the same logic not apply for list? To be more specific, why do I NOT see the need to declare that the list 'l' is global in test()?

Comment: avoid global variables, use classes or even singletons, you'll have less problems.

Comment: My guess is that lists are objects and the `m` is a primitive.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I want to understand the logic behind it, even though global declarations tend to be troublesome. Also, the answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183633/unable-to-modify-a-global-int-but-can-modify-a-list-how) says its due to assignment and append, but in my case, I am doing assignment in both cases.

Comment: I'm letting some other gold badge python owner reopen it if they feel like it.  But you're not assigning `l` when you do `l[1] = something`. You're still using `l` reference.

Comment: check the answer of delnan out (item assignment): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4630641/4151472

Comment: @RichArt That clears it up. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. :-) I was about to write a regular answer instead of a comment. But somehow I couldn't commit the answer when I was done... :-(